# how to implement autocomplete in cascading dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I am using mvc2 with c# ASP.Net. iam trying to implement cascaded dropdownlist, wherein my first dropdown is named group and my second one is build group. so on selecting the group its respective build groups are to be displayed in my 2nd dropdown list..Both the dropdowns should have autocomplete feature.
Plz help me to solve the issue..
Thanks and regards

Comment: Generally write-this-large-feature-for-me posts aren't answered.  Take a stab at it yourself, update your post to include code samples, and be specific about what's not working and people are more likely to respond.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Adam Terlson. But for other people's reference, I achieved this by setting up the second autocomplete on the `autocompleteselect` event of the first, and filtering the JSON array using jQueries grep function. Something like this:

```
$('.autoCompleteCategory').bind('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui) { 
    $('.autoCompleteItem').autocomplete({ source: $.grep(items, function(el, i) {return el.sector.toLowerCase() == ui.item.value.toLowerCase();})});
});
```